# hibernate mode not listed by xfce although "allowed"

Tags: xfce, power-management

Hibernate is not listed as a logout option in xfce4:

[image: screen shot]

The [XFCE doc](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/faq) suggests to check `xfce4-power-manager`, but there seems to be no problem:

```
>xfce4-power-manager --no-deamon --debug
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate is authorized=TRUE
```

How can I use hibernate? This is crucial for this computer, since I don't seem to have any way to use `deep` mode of sleep on suspend, and under `s2idle` it uses up 3 W of power, which empties the whole battery within hours.

Full output of the command:

```
TRACE[xfpm-main.c:210] xfpm_start(): Starting the power manager
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:679] xfpm_xfconf_init(): lock screen TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for lock-screen-suspend-hibernate
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for critical-power-level
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for show-brightness-popup
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for handle-brightness-keys
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-step-count
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for hibernate-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for sleep-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for battery-button-action
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-level-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-level-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-slider-min-level
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-enabled
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-on-ac-sleep
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-on-ac-off
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-on-battery-sleep
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-on-battery-off
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for dpms-sleep-mode
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-sleep-mode-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for inactivity-sleep-mode-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-on-ac
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for brightness-on-battery
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for network-manager-sleep
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-power-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-suspend-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for logind-handle-hibernate-key
TRACE[xfpm-xfconf.c:166] xfpm_xfconf_load(): Using default configuration for heartbeat-command
TRACE[xfpm-dpms.c:72] xfpm_dpms_set_timeouts(): Settings dpms: standby=600 suspend=0 off=900

TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:289] xfpm_polkit_init_data(): Using unix session polkit subject
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 9479>, 'start-time': <uint64 349924>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.power-off', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.power-off is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 9479>, 'start-time': <uint64 349924>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.reboot', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.reboot is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 9479>, 'start-time': <uint64 349924>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.suspend', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 9479>, 'start-time': <uint64 349924>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:929] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:888] xfpm_power_add_device(): 'line-power' device added
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:929] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:888] xfpm_power_add_device(): 'battery' device added
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:897] xfpm_power_add_device(): Battery device type 'battery' detected at: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:180] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 124 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_POWER_OFF)

(xfce4-power-manager:9479): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 09:49:49.827: could not map keysym 1008ffa8 to keycode

TRACE[xfpm-button.c:180] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 213 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_HIBERNATE)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:180] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 150 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_SLEEP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:180] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 233 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_MON_BRIGHTNESS_UP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:180] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 232 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_MON_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:180] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 244 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_BATTERY)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:180] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 238 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_KBD_BRIGHTNESS_UP)
TRACE[xfpm-button.c:180] xfpm_button_xevent_key(): Grabbed key 237 : ((XfpmButtonKey) BUTTON_KBD_BRIGHTNESS_DOWN)
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:929] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o001
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:888] xfpm_power_add_device(): 'line-power' device added
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:929] xfpm_power_get_power_devices(): Power device detected at : /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_ucsi_source_psy_USBC000o002
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:888] xfpm_power_add_device(): 'line-power' device added
TRACE[xfpm-dpms.c:72] xfpm_dpms_set_timeouts(): Settings dpms: standby=300 suspend=0 off=600

TRACE[xfpm-dpms.c:347] xfpm_dpms_set_on_battery(): dpms on battery TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1449] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Prev Timeout: 600 / New Timeout: 600
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:209] xfpm_power_check_polkit_auth(): using logind suspend backend
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 9479>, 'start-time': <uint64 349924>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.suspend', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.suspend is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:345] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): polkit request: (('unix-process', {'pid': <uint32 9479>, 'start-time': <uint64 349924>}), 'org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate', @a{ss} {}, uint32 0, '')
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:366] xfpm_polkit_check_auth_intern(): Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate is authorized=TRUE
TRACE[xfpm-power.c:1449] xfpm_update_blank_time(): Prev Timeout: 600 / New Timeout: 600
TRACE[xfpm-manager.c:650] xfpm_manager_inhibit_sleep_systemd(): Inhibiting systemd sleep: handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key:handle-lid-switch
** (xfce4-power-manager:9479): WARNING **: 09:49:49.901: No outputs have backlight property
(xfce4-power-manager:9479): xfce4-power-manager-WARNING **: 09:49:49.907: It seems the kernel brightness switch handling value was not restored properly on exit last time, xfce4-power-manager will try to restore it this time.
xfce4-power-manager-Message: 09:49:49.932: Set kernel brightness switch to 0
TRACE[xfpm-backlight.c:269] xfpm_backlight_brightness_on_ac_settings_changed(): Alarm on ac timeout changed 9
TRACE[xfpm-backlight.c:290] xfpm_backlight_brightness_on_battery_settings_changed(): Alarm on battery timeout changed 120
(xfce4-power-manager:9479): xfconf-WARNING **: 09:49:49.937: Failed to set property "xfce4-power-manager::/xfce4-power-manager/brightness-switch": Operation was cancelled
xfce4-power-manager-Message: 09:49:49.961: Set kernel brightness switch to 0
TRACE[xfpm-polkit.c:237] xfpm_polkit_free_data(): Destroying Polkit data
TRACE[xfpm-manager.c:491] xfpm_manager_alarm_timeout_cb(): Alarm inactivity timeout id 2
TRACE[xfpm-manager.c:491] xfpm_manager_alarm_timeout_cb(): Alarm inactivity timeout id 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This computer was missing swap space. Following [this](https://www.computernetworkingnotes.com/linux-tutorials/how-to-create-swap-partition-in-linux.html) I have created and activated a swap partition larger than RAM, and now xfce offers to hibernate.